# collapse('show') breaks toggling in Bootstrap3 collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap3 collapse that toggles nicely - that is when I open one section the other section gets closed.

I want my collapse to start opened on specific section so I call:

```
$('mysection').collapse('show');
```

It works but since that moment that section will not toggle-close the other section when opened by mouse click.

http://jsfiddle.net/rh4vcbxd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add `in` class to the default open section, as [documented](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).
If you want to open it via javascript then you can do like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("[data-target='#sectionId']").trigger('click');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rh4vcbxd/1/